# Improving the arrangement and layout of my listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm having trouble with Visual Basic. I'm trying to make my listbox look like this:

[image]

However it ends up like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can organise the data? Also, how can I make the total number of universities fixed at the bottom and the "university name" "Abbreviation"at the top? How do I add a vertical scroll bar? Also, how can I calculate the total number of students at the bottom?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub picList_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles picList.Click
    frmList.Show()
    frmList.lstShow.Items.Clear()
    Dim fmtStr As String = "{0,-0}{1,-20}{2,-15}{3,-20}{4,-25}"
    Dim A As Integer
    With frmList.lstShow.Items
        .Add(String.Format(fmtStr, "University Name", "Abbreviation", "State", "Accredited Year", "Total Students"))


        For A = 0 To N - 1
            .Add(String.Format(fmtStr, Names(A), Abbreviation(A), State(A), Accredited(A), Total(A)))
        Next
        .Add(String.Format(fmtStr, "", "", "", "", ""))
        .Add("Total of " & N & " Universities.")
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest: I wouldn't use a listbox for this issue.
it would be easier to use a Datagridview and some labels to display the totals.
If you use a dgv you could write some function that sums up all values in the column "Total Students" and displays the value in a specific label.

Anyway, to add a vertical scrollbar you need to give your listbox a fixed size (Autosize= false) and AutoScroll=true in the GUI Editor.